# How to get isotope to avoid gaps with variable size tiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Is there a way to get isotope to order the grid in the way that there are no gaps?

I see the elements changing places in few of the demos but can't achieve the effect myself. Like here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/layout-modes.html

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/crappish/zvRy5/

As you can see, when you resize the "result", the grid changes alright but at certain widths, white gaps appear in the mosaic. Which is highly unfortunate. :(

Comment: as i played this the demos on http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/ - there's always can be a place for a gap on resizing - try adding new elements here and resize: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-gutters.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up writing my own extension (perfectMasonry) which does not leave gaps, but instead lays out perfect "brick wall". :) I'll try to publish it (GitHub, mayhaps) as soon as I get some free time to clean it up.

Edit: Here be the perfectMasonry extension: https://github.com/zonear/isotope-perfectmasonry

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman AND a scholar.

Comment: Heheh. Thank you! Hope it works for you :)

Comment: I'm getting a 'Uncaught TypeError: Property '_perfectMasonryReset' of object #<Object> is not a function' when I try the perfectMasonry - Any ideas? EDIT: Nevermind! I'd not copied the perfectMasonry script correctly!

Comment: This is awesome, it should be in the core imho.
I hope this gets updated for isotope v2. I might lend a hand.

Comment: Grant, help would be appreciated. I don't currently have any time to build support for V2 so if you want to help where I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTxXZ/1/) and [image: that screenshot] - while observing the numbers in your divs - you see that the next masonry element up (the red element 5) can not possibly fit in the white square as it must come after element 4; so where it must end up means, that, with only three rows fitting, you'll get a white gap. Maybe you can use Isotope's *shuffle* and *reLayout* methods and sacrifice ordering your elements in a strict order?