# How to make sure there is no empty gaps with divs and isotope

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm trying to create a grid layout at http://www.gablabelle.com/.

I have multiple divs floating with isotope and I wonder why there is some empty spaces and why the floating divs are not filling the gaps.

[image]

Same problem as here: [How to avoid gaps using Isotope with Masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738542/how-to-avoid-gaps-using-isotope-with-masonry-layout)

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your items are in a certain order which you don't want to "destroy" by calling the shuffle method, this will be inevitable. Then, even when shuffling, you can't guarantee the type of fit you want with some elements spanning two columns. You might be able to [leverage this plugin instead](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417) but it's a very different logic.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just do with it I guess ;-)

Comment: Looks good. If you have many visitors using smartphones and tablet devices, you might want to consider the hover effects as they don't work on devices without a mouse...

Comment: Yes but I don't the title of the photos are really important anyway in this case. I'm simply showcasing my work and notes (normal posts) won't have images.